# Running C++ Cairo without using pkg-config

Tags: c++, graphics

Does anyone know how to build the minimal Cairo graphics program without using pkg-config?  I refer to the example on:

```
http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#compilation_flags
```

Comment: I suppose you can see what `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo` returns and just use those flags, but why would you want to avoid pkg-config?

Comment: for the same reason I don't want to use ANT - its non standard

Comment: but thanks for the comment - at least I can see what I need

Comment: I don't know your exact situation so this may be presumptuous, but pkg-config is fairly platform-independent and widely available on machines that have any compilers installed, so I wouldn't avoid it without a concrete reason. It can also make your build more portable by returning platform-specific flags when needed.